# Update column from Base64 to string (natively in SQL)

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I've been trying to figure this out for two days now and would really appreciate some help. I've imported data from a csv where one field contained html data encoded in base64.

The idea is to loop over every row and run FROM_BASE64 on it.

How do I structure a query that:

1. Loops over all lines
2. Calls FROM_BASE64 for each line
3. Runs UPDATE (or similar functionality) on that same row and column

I'm running MariaDB (MySQL equivalent).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you haven't given us any information about the table or column in question you'll have to update my example with the correct information.

```
update thetable set thecolumn = FROM_BASE64(thecolumn)
```